# Getting images from DB in MYSQL, PDO and putting into slider foreach

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

This is my code, actually, it actually retrieves data, but, its looking bad.

I use Jquery, (nivoSlider), and Bootstrap loaded in that order.

I have 2 results on DB, it successfully fetched title, description and other information, but it looks bad formatted, or I cannot make it to display the information correctly.

QUESTION: How can I achieve From this-> http://prntscr.com/5imr6e to this-> http://prntscr.com/5imy35 - With its proper thumbnails ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM homeslider ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 6";
        $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $row = $query->fetchAll();
        return $row;
    }

    ?>
    <?php 
$data = getContent();  
foreach ($data as $row) {
 echo '<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
 <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
 ';
   $id = $row['id'];
   $titulo = $row['titulo'];
   $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
   $link = $row['link'];
   $imgurl = $row['imgurl'];
   $ultimo_update = $row['ultimo_update']; 
   $captions = '';   
 }   
 echo'
 <img src="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-thumb="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-transition="fold" title="#htmlcaption_'.$id.'" />'; ?>

    <?php $captions = '<div id="htmlcaption_'.$id.'" class="nivo-html-caption">
     '.$titulo.'<br/>'.$descripcion.'<span class="nivoButtonSpan"><a href="'.$link.'" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#000;">Leer más <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a></span>';?>
     </div> <!-- Close htmlcaption_# -->

     <?php echo $captions; ?>
</div> <!-- Close slider -->
</div> <!-- Close slider-wrapper -->
</div> <!-- Close wrapper -->
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What kind of help do you need? do you want to optimize this code? Do you want an alternative? Please specify.

Comment: Hi, please check this slider http://prntscr.com/5imy35

I cant see more than 1 image, and its ugly formatted, im doing something wrong

Comment: @JCC: Please do not offer money to people for helping you.  I've removed that from your title.

Comment: But that is what i wanted to, it that ilegal here?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Sorry, you both start with "J" :-P

Comment: @JCC: It's not allowed here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty

Comment: @RocketHazmat ok thank you, i apologize. Could you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first thing to do is switch this to use a more readable output syntax - breaking in and out of php instead of echoing all the html as complete strings. Additionally i think you want all the images to be slides but im pretty sure you are actually creating a slider for each image...

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
                <?php // lets use printf since the majority of this is static with just a couple vars ?>
                <?php printf(
                    '<img src="images/slider/%s" data-thumb="images/slider/%s" data-transition="fold" title="#htmlcaption_%s" />',    
                    $row['imgurl'], 
                    $row['imgurl'], 
                    $row['id']
                );  ?>                    
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div> <!-- Close slider -->

        <?php // output the captions ?>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
            <div id="htmlcaption_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="nivo-html-caption">
                <?php echo $row['titulo']; ?>
                <br />
                <?php echo $row['descripcion'] ?>
                <span class="nivoButtonSpan">
                    <a href="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#000;">Leer más <i class="glyphicon   glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div> <!-- Close slider-wrapper -->
</div> <!-- Close wrapper -->
```

We could further optimize this by building a big string of the captions in the loop so that we do not need loop over the array twice:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <?php
                // initialize captions as an empty string 
                $captions = ''; 
            ?>
            <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
                <?php // lets use printf since the majority of this is static with just a couple vars ?>
                <?php printf(
                    '<img src="images/slider/%s" data-thumb="images/slider/%s" data-transition="fold" title="#htmlcaption_%s" />',    
                    $row['imgurl'], 
                    $row['imgurl'], 
                    $row['id']
                );  ?>
                <?php ob_start(); // start a buffer ?>
                <div id="htmlcaption_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="nivo-html-caption">
                    <?php echo $row['titulo']; ?>
                    <br />
                    <?php echo $row['descripcion'] ?>
                    <span class="nivoButtonSpan">
                        <a href="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#000;">Leer más <i class="glyphicon   glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <?php
                    // get the buffer contents, append them to $captions 
                    // and then clear the buffer and stop buffering
                    $captions .= ob_get_clean();  
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div> <!-- Close slider -->

        <?php // output the captions ?>
        <?php echo $captions; ?>
    </div> <!-- Close slider-wrapper -->
</div> <!-- Close wrapper -->
```

Comment: Hi, your code works great!! But after all images are loaded and shown, when the animation returns from last slide to the first it behave strange, can you please take a look.
http://esve1.mooo.com/slider/
 I appreciate all your help! pm your mail so i can tip u pro

Comment: You need to output the captions **outside** of `div#slider`. Updated the second example so you can see the full structure.

Comment: YOU ARE MY GOD SAVIOR. THANK YOU! TIP STILL PENDING IF YOU WANT IT =) THANKS!

Comment: No tip required. You can upvote the answer if you want though :-)

Comment: sorry i cant upvote :(

"Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not closing the `nivoslider div`:

```
echo'
 <img src="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-thumb="images/slider/'.$imgurl.'" data-transition="fold" title="#htmlcaption_'.$id.'" />'; ?>

    <?php $captions = 'CLOSE HERE: </div><div id="htmlcaption_'.$id.'" class="nivo-html-caption">
     '.$titulo.'<br/>'.$descripcion.'<span class="nivoButtonSpan"><a href="'.$link.'" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#000;">Leer más <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-share-alt"></i></a></span>';?>
     </div> <!-- Close htmlcaption_# -->
```